# WCF: ServiceHost problem (cached adresses?)

Tags: wcf, tcp

i use a WCF-Service.

It workes fine, and if i use a forbidden IP it shows me a message.
But if i change the ip in my textbox to the right IP it will be again catch the TCP exception, with the OLD IP... The IP-string in the textbox is the corret one and all variables contains the right IP...

The exception:

> CommunicationException TCP-Fehler
>   (10049: Die angeforderte Adresse ist
>   in diesem Kontext ungültig) beim
>   Lauschen am
>   IP-Endpunkt=192.168.178.**2**:7997.

Should be 192.168.178.**25**
And after correcting the IP in the textbox and restarting the server i get the same exception with the old IP...

Here is my method:
I create all ressources new in this methode.
Only the ServiceHost host; Variable is stored outside the methode and i tried to set it null before starting or after exception.

Configure Host:

```
private void MenuItemServerStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            **[ omitted ]**

            //Define base addresses so all 
            //endPoints can go under it

            Uri tcpAdrs = new Uri("net.tcp://" +
                textBoxLocalIP.Text.ToString() + ":" +
                textBoxPort.Text.ToString() + "/WPFHost/");

            Uri httpAdrs = new Uri("http://" +
                textBoxLocalIP.Text.ToString() + ":" +
                (int.Parse(textBoxPort.Text.ToString()) + 1).ToString() +
                "/WPFHost/");

            Uri[] baseAdresses = { tcpAdrs, httpAdrs };

            try
            {
                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ChatService.ChatService), baseAdresses);
            }
            catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    **[ omitted ]**
                }

                return;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                **[ omitted ]**
            }

            NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true);
            //Updated: to enable file transefer of 64 MB
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = (int)67108864;
            tcpBinding.MaxBufferSize = 67108864;
            tcpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = (int)67108864;
            tcpBinding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 67108864;
            tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 67108864;
            tcpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 67108864;
            tcpBinding.MaxConnections = 100;

            **[ omitted ]**

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ChatService.IChatService),
                                    tcpBinding, "tcp");

            //Define Metadata endPoint, So we can 
            //publish information about the service
            ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave =
                           new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding(),
                "net.tcp://" + textBoxLocalIP.Text.ToString() + ":" +
                (int.Parse(textBoxPort.Text.ToString()) - 1).ToString() +
                "/WPFHost/mex");
```

Start host (Exception):

```
            try
            {
                **host.Open();** **//Exception here !!!**
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                **[ omitted ]**
            }
            finally
            {
                if (host.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                {
                    ((StatusBarItem)statusBar1.Items.GetItemAt(0)).Content = "Gestartet";
                    MenuItemServerStop.IsEnabled = true;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: There's a *lot* of code here to read - it would be great if you could isolate the problem so that you only have to post 5-20 lines of code.  Also, why are you doing `Text.ToString()`? Text is string.

Comment: In the first codeblock i do configuration-stuff and in the second i open the host connection. There i get the Exception. I know its a lot of code, but i dont know if i did sime mistake in the configuration. host.open() throws the ecxeption, but the ip in the exceptionmessage is a old one. But i alway create a new host and other the other objects too.

Comment: @user437899: Have you debugged through after assigning `host = new ServiceHost` and see if the IP was actually configured? Or maybe the Uri bounced from it being assigned with a textbox field?

Comment: Yes i debugged through and the IP is alway the correct one from the textbox... And I cant find the wrong IP in any hostproperty.

Comment: I located the problem at this adress: Uri tcpAdrs = new Uri("net.tcp://" +                 textBoxLocalIP.Text.ToString() + ":" +                 textBoxPort.Text.ToString() + "/WPFHost/"); But the Uri is recreated properly. And i can see in debugmode the right adress, but the exception goes with the old IP... weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch that there may be some static state associated with the channel runtime infrastructure for HTTP bindings, which maintains details of HTTP listeners keyed by service Uri. If you are not properly tearing down ServiceHost instances which threw on Open, perhaps the old details remain registered in this static state.

What happens in your catch block following the call to `host.Open()`? If you are not calling `host.Abort()` and `host.Dispose()` on the instances which threw on Open, this might be the problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, i tried host.Abort(). This cause the host to get into closed-state. host.Dispose() is no Methode from ServiceHost (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost_methods.aspx) i have to use this: ((IDisposable)host).Dispose(); (information from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c7c83c6d-37a9-45a9-8037-05754aab65fd) But this doesent helped. The TCP-IP is still corrupt. (i also tried to set host = null, but no effect)