# Address of new ServiceHost always same as the old one?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.5

I have the following test code which first tries to open a ServiceHost on an invalid address, then when it faults it calls both `Abort()` and `Dispose` (the latter probably isn't required).  Then it creates a new ServiceHost and attempts to open it on another (valid) address, but it still generates an error saying that the old address is invalid.

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      TestHost("net.tcp://0.0.0.1:8081/TestUri");
      TestHost("net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8081/TestUri");
   }

   static void TestHost(string address)
   {
      ServiceHost host = null;
      try
      {
         host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyContract), new Uri(address));
         host.Open();
         Console.WriteLine("Host opened successfully");
         host.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         if (host != null)
         {
            host.Abort();
            ((IDisposable)host).Dispose();
         }
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
   }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyContract
{
   [OperationContract]
   void Method();
} 

class MyContract : IMyContract
{
   public void Method()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Method Called");
   }
}
```

This generates the following output:

```
A TCP error (10049: The requested address is not valid in its context) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=0.0.0.1:8081.
A TCP error (10049: The requested address is not valid in its context) occurred while listening on IP Endpoint=0.0.0.1:8081.
```

Note that the endpoint is the *same* in both errors. (If I reverse the operations, the first call will succeed and the second will fail).

Seems to be some cache in the works here, but how can I clear it and have the new ServiceHost use the address I provided instead of the old address?!

Comment: Odd. Does the special "0.0.0.0" address not support default port numbers?

Comment: That has nothing to do with it, it appears. I modified the code to include the port number, still same result. And I also tried it with other addresses, such as 127.0.0.1 or my actual IP with the same result. (And with other invalid addresses, such as 255.255.255.0 or similar)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm much help either, other than pointing out others have had similar problems but without an obvious solution.

- [ServiceHost fail to Open() again with new ServiceHost instance when it failed for the first time in WCF self-host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220172/servicehost-fail-to-open-again-with-new-servicehost-instance-when-it-failed-fo)
- [WCF: ServiceHost problem (cached adresses?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610643/wcf-servicehost-problem-cached-adresses)

A suggestion: I have found that the call to `Close()` doesn't immediately shut down the whole stack, right down to the actual socket; it can happen several seconds later.  Usually this manifests itself as errors saying ports are in use when you try to reopen them soon after closing them.  I wonder if something similar is going on in your test code, and the second call is trying to reopen the previous host because it's still floating around somewhere until it is tidied up.  Try putting a delay in between the calls to `TestHost` and/or forcing garbage collection and see if that changes the behaviour.

A question: do you need to bind to a specific IP address?  Under what circumstances could it be invalid and you be able to retry a different address?  Could you bind to all addresses (e.g.: net.tcp://localhost:8081/TestUri)?

Comment: This is annoying. Thanks for the links though, even though as you say they do not provide a clear solution.  Waiting after the `Close()` call or doing GC.Collect() does not change anything in this case unfortunately.

Comment: The IP address is user configurable in our application, just for the purpose of allowing binding to a specific interface or address of the customer's choice.  Thus, we would like to allow re-configuration as well, for example if he/she enters an invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this happens however the way to get around it would be to specify a port in the URI of the valid call.

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyContract), new Uri("net.tcp://0.0.0.0:8081/TestUri"));
```

Or alternatively you can specify a particular port on the first call.

Comment: This doesn't help. Well, it does if the second call specifies a *different* port than the first failing call apparently.